# nested select query resulting in entire table

Tags: php, mysql, select, nested

The following nested select query is resulting in display of entire table.

```
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM create_job
 WHERE item_no IN (SELECT item_no FROM item WHERE order_no IN (SELECT order_no FROM `order` WHERE delivery_date='$delivery_date'))
;");
```

Comment: What is the error? What are you expecting to be displayed?

Comment: the query should return only about item_nos from orders whose delivery date is $delivery_date. But my query is returning the entire table create_job.

Comment: can you share the tables? I see nothing wrong tbh.. Does $delivery_date have a value when echo'd out?